# Redis ZINTERSTORE of multiple ZRANGEBYSCORE in a single command call?

Tags: redis

*The question is about these  Redis commands  and how to use 3° and 4° in a single call.*

1)

```
HMSET key field value [field value ...]
```

2)

```
ZADD key [NX|XX] [CH] [INCR] score member [score member ...]
```

3)

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE key min max [WITHSCORES] [LIMIT offset count]
```

4)

```
ZINTERSTORE destination numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]
```

i have thousand of points with x y z coords: p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7...

```
HMSET p_1 x 10 y 20 z 30
HMSET p_2 x 20 y 30 z 40
HMSET p_3 x 30 y 40 z 50
...
...
```

i have three sorted set : xsorted, ysorted, zsorted

```
zadd xsorted 10 p_1
zadd xsorted 20 p_2
zadd xsorted 30 p_3
...
```

(all x as scores and keys of points p_1,p_2,p_3... as members

```
zadd ysorted 20 p_1
zadd ysorted 30 p_2
zadd ysorted 40 p_3
....
```

(all y as scores and  keys of points p_1,p_2,p_3... as members

```
zadd zsorted 30 p_1
zadd zsorted 40 p_2
zadd zsorted 50 p_3
...
```

(all z as scores and keys of points p_1,p_2,p_3... as members

i have range_x, range_y, range_z client-side as results of ZRANGEBYSCORE :

```
range_x = ZRANGEBYSCORE xsorted min max    
range_y = ZRANGEBYSCORE ysorted min max 
range_z = ZRANGEBYSCORE zsorted min max
```

i have xyzinter client-side as result of ZINTERSTORE:

```
ZINTERSTORE xyzinter 3 range_x range_y range_z
```

So xyzinter has  the keys of points with x,y,z coordinates in a range of values. Good , i need it.

There is the possibility to execute the commands up described, in a faster way, with only "two" calls?

Something like:

1)

```
ZINTERSTORE xyzinter 3 
ZRANGEBYSCORE xsorted min max    
ZRANGEBYSCORE ysorted min max 
ZRANGEBYSCORE zsorted min max
```

2)

```
ZRANGE xyzinter start stop
```

Thanks in advance
Mario

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to call both commands. You could, however, wrap them in a Lua script that will run server-side and then your client will make a single call to Redis. Read more about Lua scripting in Redis at https://redis.io/commands/eval

Answer (score 0):

A Better solution than i found: Using the three arrays "sort_id" created at the beginning in Ruby , before store it as sorted sets in Redis. I only get Redis the min,max. ~100points/secs with three resulted sorted array to intersect 
with 30-40 elements each one. But still too slow (Ruby Client-Side)

```
def points_id_in_range crng

    sort_key=[:x=>"sort_x",:y=>"sort_y",:z=>"sort_z"]
    rrng = {:x=>[],:y=>[],:z=>[]}

    [:x,:y,:z].each{|sym|

        rrng[sym] << $r.ZRANGEBYSCORE(sort_key[sym], crng[sym].min, 
        crng[sym].max, :LIMIT,0,1)[0].to_i

        rrng[syn] << $r.ZREVRANGEBYSCORE(sort_key[sym], 
        crng[sym].max, crng[sym].min, :LIMIT,0,1)[0].to_i

    }

    #intersection in Ruby

    @@sort_id[:x][rrng[:x].min..rrng[:x].max] &
    @@sort_id[:y][rrng[:y].min..rrng[:y].max] &
    @@sort_id[:z][rrng[:z].min..rrng[:z].max] 

end
```